# How to get rid of the error of keep_alive?

Tags: discord.py

```
from keep_alive import keep_alive
```

with error

> Import "keep_alive" could not be resolved

same directory, have the keep alive file
anyone help me?
basically how do do keep alive

Comment: Do you have a file named ```keep_alive.py```?

Comment: yes i do have the file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask

from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')


app.route('/')

def main():
  return "Bot is online."


def run():
  app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8000)


def keep_alive():
  server = Thread(target = run)
  server.start()
```

This is what the keep_alive file contains, and name it like host.py or something. If you are naming it host.py then in your main.py you should add this too.

```
from host import keep_alive
keep_alive() #added at the bottom after all commands
```